# Drop-down menu postback for non-JavaScript version of asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have two dropdown menus, and one gets filtered when the user selects a value from the other. But I will also need to support a non-javascript version and am wondering how to achieve a postback via onselectedindexchanged?  I know that i can't use the AutoPostBack property for example, so how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not? By definition, the "non-javascript" version would imply a postback. Btw, this would be for a `DropDownList`, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, but after disabling JavaScript it appears that SelectedIndexChanged is no longer getting called...Can you suggest another reason for this not firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the post-back features (which `SelectedIndexChanged` is one) of `ASP.Net` and have javascript disabled. ASP.Net and WebForms have a tight coupling with javascript to perform most all its posting functionality including some basic things like maintaining `ViewState`.

If disabled javascript is a requirement, you might want to consider using an [MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) approach, but even that will still be a very limited web user experience.